# Triggering action when back in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

There are two ways of back to previous state in mobile device using ionic framework, which is via `ion-nav-back-button` and the device back button itself.

What function should i call should i need to trigger an action before back to previous state when clicking `ion-nav-back-button` and pressing device back button?

Answer (score 0):

I think the below should provide the solution you are looking for

The only thing is that I'm not sure if this solution will work 100% for hardware back button on all devices....

```
                // run this function when either hard or soft back button is pressed
            var doCustomBack = function() {
            // your custom handler code here
            .....
                //});

                $ionicHistory.goBack();
            };

            // override soft back
            // framework calls $rootScope.$ionicGoBack when soft back button is pressed
            var oldSoftBack = $rootScope.$ionicGoBack;
            $rootScope.$ionicGoBack = function() {
                doCustomBack();
            };
            var deregisterSoftBack = function() {
                $rootScope.$ionicGoBack = oldSoftBack;
            };

            // override hard back
            // registerBackButtonAction() returns a function which can be used to deregister it
            var deregisterHardBack = $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(
                doCustomBack, 101
            );

            // cancel custom back behaviour
            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                deregisterHardBack();
                deregisterSoftBack();
            });
```

Comment: will try this and give feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"
    ng-click="myGoBack()">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>

function MyCtrl($scope, $ionicHistory) {
  $scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.goBack();
  };
}
```

Comment: wasn't this suppose to trigger only when nav-back-button is click but not the mobile device hardware back button ?